# Line-height in code-tag

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <style>
  #article * {
    line-height: 2;
  }
  
  #article pre code {
    line-height: 1;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="article">
  <pre>
    <code>
!LOOP
.formula U|xiindex = U|xiindex + 1
.. U|xiindex ausgeben:
'U|xiindex'
    </code>
  </pre>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The line-height-attribute in the `#article pre code`-part of the css seems to have no effect. What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

Screenshots:
Full css:
[image]

Second commented out:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean?  It does change the height of each line.

Comment: What makes you think it has no effect? (Hint: It does have an effect)

Comment: Actually It works... I don't understand your question / problem...

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work for me. I tested in Firefox and Chrome, and there the existence of the second css-group seems to make no difference. I will post screeshots.

Comment: I agree with @Nils-o-mat here. The *first* `line-height` does work, the *second* should reset to a normal line-height but it doesn't do that. I changed it to `line-height:1em;` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: seems like the code tag is making the css invalid in some way as without the code tag or if you replace it with another element, the style works fine.. but why does it work when you type in larger line-height, it's like inheriting the line-height and using it as base line-height..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This explains it better.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height

#article is a block-level element, so the code below sets the minimum line-height for the inline elements inside it. In this case, it is "2".

```
#article > * {
    line-height: 2;
}
```

The next code, sets the line-height of the non replaced inline element "code" to "1", but is ignored or drowned out since the parent element has set a minimum of "2". Hence you will only noticed a change when you set it higher.

```
#article pre code {
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Setting display:block or inline-block as below would set its own minimum and prevent it from inheriting the parent line-height.

```
#article pre code {
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After some research, I still have no definite reason, but at least, I found out that it seems to have something to do with the `code` tag.

So, I figured out a workaround:

```css
  #article > * {
    line-height: 2;
  }
  
  #article pre {
    line-height: 1;
  }
```

```html
<div id="article">
  <pre>
    <code>
!LOOP
.formula U|xiindex = U|xiindex + 1
.. U|xiindex ausgeben:
'U|xiindex'
    </code>
  </pre>
</div>
```